# Update a SharePoint list from another list using Nintex workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list, nintex-workflow

I have 2 lists: List A and List B.

List B is a mirror copy of List A.

Currently both lists have exactly the same content. 300 items with 40 columns per item.

I want edits to an item in List A (multiple fields changed, say 20), to be reflected in List B using Nintex.

I know I can use 'Update Item' action of Nintex but that would require me to configure logic for all the 40 fields and that would be tedious.

Is there any other shorter way to update all fields of List B when an item is updated in List A?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm afraid not.

The only other option that is coming to my mind would be to delete the entry in List B and the use the "Copy Item" action to create a new copy of the current item.

However - depending on how frequent the items in "List A" change, you might want to implement another approach (I'm assuming you would have a workflow that kicks off automatically on change). Because if two changes happen to the same item, the first change would kick off the workflow, the second might not because the first is already running. Instead you could implement a workflow, that is creating a copy of "List A" on a regular schedule.